# tmux: username doesn't update in status bar when set using `set -g status-right`?

Tags: linux, shell, tmux

I want to display the username in the right-side of the status in `tmux` and have it update automatically when changing user using e.g. `sudo -u`.

I attempt to do this using `#(whoami)`:

```
set -g status-right "#{?window_bigger,[#{window_offset_x}#,#{window_offset_y}] ,} #[fg=colour47]#(whoami) %H:%M %d-%b-%y"
```

Furthermore, I set the update interval to 2 seconds:

```
set -g status-interval 2
```

However, when changing user using e.g. `sudo -u`, the status bar doesn't update the username, but the time keeps updating:

[image]

How can I make `tmux` update the username, whenever I change user?

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually *changing* users for the whole environment. You're just opening a new shell that is running as 'root', but its parent shell is still under your account, as is the master 'tmux' process. Tmux has very little knowledge about what happened inside that shell.

When you're running the `whoami` command, the process tree looks like this:

```
tmux server              [nlykkei]
└─ bash                  [nlykkei]
   └─ sudo -u root bash  [setuid root]
      └─ bash            [root]
         └─ whoami       [root]
```

When tmux needs to expand `#(whoami)`, it takes the simplest approach and runs the command directly. (It actually has no way to run that command through the triply-nested shell that you started.) So the output always reflects the account that owns the 'tmux' server process.

```
tmux server              [nlykkei]
├─ bash                  [nlykkei]
│  └─ sudo -u root bash  [setuid root]
│     └─ bash            [root]
└─ whoami                [nlykkei]
```

Unfortunately, I can't think of a good way to actually export the information from a nested shell to tmux. There already are `#{pane_title}` and `#{window_name}`, both of which are settable using escape codes, but it of course they already have a different purpose.

One way that *might* work is:

```
tmux set -g status-right '#(ps -o user= -q $(pgrep -t #{s/^.dev.//:pane_tty} -x -n bash))'

tmux set -g status-right '#(ps -t #{pane_tty} -o user= --sort start | tail -1)'
```

Comment: Thank you - isn't it only a two-level nested shell? There are only two instances of `bash`.

Comment: And one instance of `sudo`, which isn't a shell but still remains running the whole time (due to having to close PAM sessions when the shell exits).

Comment: Since `sudo` isn't a shell, that makes it a two-level nested shell ;)